# Java to JavaScript array of arrays?

Tags: java, javascript, json

I've to create from Java a JSON structure like this one:

> [ [ timestamp , number ],[ timestamp , number ] ]

for using it on Highcharts graphs.

I've used a "LinkedList of LinkedList" structure that I've found formatting in json in the same way, and it works.

I wished to know if there's another way to do it.
A LinkedList of LinkedList sounds weird..

**EDIT:**

Maybe the question wasn't clear.
I'm not asking how to convert the array-of-arrays in json but WHAT to convert.

In my case I know the result of the conversion and I can choose the starting structure.
Other structures, instead of "LinkedList of LinkedLists" that json-ized are like this:

> [ [ x, y ] , [ z, k ] , ... ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If u dont want to use any collection class then by simply using following code u can make the string required to u for JSON.In following code u can keep the num variable value dynamic.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("[");
        int num = 5;
        for(int i=0;i<num;i++)
        {
            sb.append("[");
            sb.append(new Date().getTime() + "," + (i+1));
            sb.append("]");
            if((i+1)<num)
                sb.append(",");
        }
        sb.append("]");
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way? You haven't really said how you've already done it.  I've found [Json-lib](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/) easy to use and reliable, and it should turn a Java array-of-arrays into JSON for you.

Comment: I know how to made the structures in JSON (I'm using the JAX-RS because I'm building a restful web service). I'm asking which should be the starting structure instead of my LinkedList-of-LinkedLists.

Comment: Did you try an array of arrays in Java?

Answer (score 0):

Good day!

LinkedList-of-LinkedLists is a bad way to do it, as it does not allow you to extend your structure further.
You'd better take a glance at how it is implemented in existent Java-JSON wrappers.
You surely need to make some class which would have encapsulated a linked list inside it. This way you could make even more complex structures without loosing readability.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `List` of arrays:

```
List<long[]> hcData = new ArrayList<long[]>();
//add the pairs
hcData.add(new long[]{date.getTime(), number});
```

Just make sure your list (`hcData`) will be sorted according to the `date`, so that you don't have to play with it on the client side.